# How to setup a cron job that spans the night and runs every 15mins

Tags: cron

How to set up a cron job to run from 2300 hrs to 0515 hrs(next morning) from Sunday to Thursday(job ends on Friday morning)

This is a specific requirement since my hostgator server is set to Chicago time and I need a job to run from Monday to Friday Indian Standard Time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for questions about programming, but we will not do all the work for you. Please show us what you have tried, what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: Tried all the usual combinations like 23-5 in hours field etc. Did not work. Pls refer to Iskuhar's detailed response why - needs three separate jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need three cron expressions to achieve exactly what you ask for:

1. 23:00 - 23:59 (Sun-Thu, every 15 min)

   ```
   */15 23 * * 0-4 command
   ```
2. 00:00 - 4:59 (Mon-Fri, every 15 min)

   ```
   */15 0-4 * * 1-5 command
   ```
3. 5:00, 5:15 (Mon-Fri)

   ```
   0,15 5 * * 1-5 command
   ```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a ton. Have added the jobs. Will update after watching it tomorrow morning (Indian time).

Comment: This is working perfectly since Sunday night..will update again on Friday. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Works perfectly...stopped on time today. Thanks a ton again :)